# Upgrade path for service fabric from 5.7.198 to 6.0

Tags: azure

Recently we started getting a message on the Azure portal that our SF version on the cluster we use will become unsupported (5.7.198). Which I interpret as that we need to upgrade to 6.0.

1. Has anyone done such an upgrade on a prod system with real customers and data that should be kept safe?
2. Is there an upgrade we should follow (i.e. go through intermediate versions)
3. Any issues that I should expect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could upgrade service fabric from 5.7.198 to 6.0 on Azure Portal.

[image]

More information about this please refer to this official document:[Upgrade an Azure Service Fabric cluster](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-upgrade).

Note: **Upgrading to a newer version maybe affect your application.** I suggest you could upgrade on your test environment firstly. Everything test fine then you could upgrade your product environment.

Comment: If it helps, please don't forget to accept it as an answer. It will help more people in the community.

Comment: Hey, 10x for the reply, but I wen't through the available docs and am aware of the above way of how to make the upgrade. The question was more like if anyone has done it and faced any issues I should be aware of :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, do you solve this issue?